# Unable to run opencv c++ functions in code blocks

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, codeblocks

I have downloaded and extracted the latest opencv-4.9.0 and installed latest code blocks-20.03.

```
When I tried to use the opencv functions like waitKey(), imread, imshow() to load an image and to display, after including the paths in the build option, I am getting various errors,

||=== Build: Debug in load_image (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
ld.exe||cannot find -lopencv_core|
ld.exe||cannot find -lopencv_highgui|
ld.exe||cannot find -lopencv_imgproc|
ld.exe||cannot find -lopencv_calib3d|
ld.exe||cannot find -lopencv_ml|
ld.exe||cannot find -lopencv_stitching|
ld.exe||cannot find -lopencv_cudaarithm|
ld.exe||cannot find -lopencv_cudabgsegm|
ld.exe||cannot find -lopencv_cudacodec|
ld.exe||cannot find -lopencv_features2d|
ld.exe||cannot find -lopencv_xfeatures2d|
ld.exe||cannot find -lopencv_contrib|
ld.exe||cannot find -lopencv_videoio|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 14 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I have made changes ad below,
build options -> search directories -> compiler -> "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\opencv\build\include

[image]

build options -> Linker settings -> (.lib)

[image]

I am getting the following compilation errors After including both the headers and the .lib files

[image]

What I have to do to run opencv functions in code blocks successfully?

Comment: You've told it what to link, but not where.  It's probably `C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\opencv\build\lib` but you didn't include that information anywhere

Comment: @possum: I have already included the path where I have made the changes. Kindly look into the description once again.
build options -> search directories -> compiler -> "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\opencv\build\include (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WraRE.jpg)
build options -> Linker settings -> (.lib)

Comment: Yes, I saw, that was not ambiguous. `include` is for headers and does not have the libraries.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to link msvc libraries into gcc, that won't work. You'll need to download libraries built for your version of gcc or build your own from source

Comment: @possum So how to fix my issue here ?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have downloaded both code blocksa and opencv for windows only.

Comment: For "windows" does not mean it will work with MinGW. That usually means it will work with `msvc` but not necessarily `MinGW`. For `c` based libraries compilers are usually compatible. For c++ they are likely not compatible unless specified otherwise. Even with msvc different versions of the compiler were not compatible with each other until Visual Studio 2015. Currently the easiest MinGW experience is to install it with [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/#installation) and use [pacman](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-opencv?repo=ucrt64) to install your  libraries.